Can not delet / dissolve Edge
I have built my model with the mirror modifier. After that, I had edges where the model was mirrored. I tried to dissolve the edges, but that did not work. So I dissolved the two faces I had, that worked partly. The face was now one face, but I still have the edge in the middle. I think it comes from the interior faces. But I also can not delete them.
So what am I doing wrong?


Dissolve or delete? Did you try both? Can you delete vertices?
